# OpenGL: Rendering a line using only GL_POINTS

Tags: c++, opengl, line

this is an assignment where I need to use OpenGL to render a line, but only using **GL_POINTS**.

I'm testing it with a horizontal line **P1(-1,-1)** to **P2(1,-1)**.

My function uses the line function y=mx+c:

```
void line2(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double precision, int r, int g, int b){


double m = 0.0;             // slope
double c = (y1 - m*x1);     // constant
double j = y1;              // starting y value

// check division by 0
if (x2-x1 == 0)
    m = 0;
else 
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);

glColor3f(r,g,b);

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (double i = x1; i < x2; i+=precision){
        j = m*i + c;        // result of y from line function
        glVertex2f(i,j);
    }
glEnd();
```

}

Calling it with:

```
line2(-1,-1,1,-1,0.000001, 102, 102, 255);
```

gives me a horizontal dashed line. It's not continuous. If I add more precision, my program hangs probably due to memory.

**Update: What I noticed now is that render multiple lines, the first one is dotted! So if I call line() multiple times, no matter the parameters, the 1st line is always dotted and the others are perfect.**

Is there a better way (formula or loop) to render a line?

Thank you!

Comment: Try using multiple draw calls (but keep them small, e.g. < 40). Split up the vertex creation into chunks (amount of vertices / 40) and issue a draw call per issue.

In OpenGL 3.3+ where you mostly do this via vertex buffers and shaders you might be able to do the folling:

1. Submit your start and endpoint via vertex buffers

2. Call a Geometry Shader to add additional vertices. Pass the precision as a uniform variable (used to push memory from CPU to GPU).

3. Render :)

Comment: You should create a vector of values first, then pass them as vertex attributes

Comment: May be you also can avoid to calculate `j` every time, because increment of j is also constant: 
`double jInc = m * precision`
And change your loop for something like that:
`for (double i = x1, j = y1; i < x2; i+=precision, j += jInc){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double m = 0.0;             // slope
double c = (y1 - m*x1);     // constant
double j = y1;              // starting y value

// check division by 0
if (x2-x1 == 0)
    m = 0;
else 
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
```

You are calculating `c` with `m==0`, so `c` always equals `j`.  Try moving the calculation of `c` to a line after `m` is calculated.

Also, when `x2-x1 == 0`, the slope should be either positive or negative infinity, not 0.  Since `inf` is hard to work with, you might need special cases to draw vertical lines.

As for other ways to draw lines from pixels, you can't go wrong with Bresenham lines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: oh you're right about calculating c too early. We learned that Bresenham isn't efficient for drawing straight horizontal/vertical lines. Hence trying to do it with the plain old line function.

What I noticed now is that if I drew 2 lines, the first one is dotted! So if I call line() multiple times, no matter the parameters, the 1st line is always dotted and the others are perfect.